# PHP - "unexpected t_variable"

Tags: php

What is my error?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in public_html/sign_up.php on line 14

For the life of me I cannot figure out what I have done wrong.

```
    include_once("../php/sign_up/connect_db.php");

    // Array for JSON response
    $response = array();

    // Check for required fields
    if (isset($_POST['firstname']) &&
        isset($_POST['surname'])   &&
        isset($_POST['postcode'])  &&
        isset($_POST['email'])     &&
        isset($_POST['phone'])

        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $surname   = $_POST['surname'];
        $postcode  = $_POST['postcode'];
        $email     = $_POST['email'];
        $phone     = $_POST['phone'];

        // Connecting to db
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

        // MySQL inserting a new row
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE 1(firstname, surname, postcode, phone, email) VALUES('$firstname', '$surname', '$postcode', '$phone', '$email')");

        // Check if row is inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            // Successfully inserted into database
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Thank you for registering.";

            // Echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // Failed to insert row
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

            // Echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

        // Echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your `if` statement doesn't have braces. Although you can get away without them (to just apply it to the next statement only) you should get into the habit of always using them - it is less prone to error that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had forgot to close the if parenthesis:

*Change*

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['postcode'])&& isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone'])
```

*to*

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['postcode'])&& isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']))
```

Comment: Disgustingly simple mistake :(. Thank you so much, however now Im returning an error with the "else" function. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/mynight/public_html/sign_up.php on line 48"

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing parenthesis:

```
if ( isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['postcode'])
     && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) )
                                                         ^ here
{
^ you probably want this too as you do have the 'else' and closing brackets
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) Horribly simple mistake. Ive now got this "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/mynight/public_html/sign_up.php on line 48"

Comment: @mynight Did you put in the `{` as well?

Comment: Indeed, Im unsure why its not happy. All braces are closed. Yet im still producing the error.

Comment: Edit: Found it. Thank you again for the help :)